# How do I vertically center and crop my image using overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to display pre-set image thumbs without stretching or shrinking the image.  My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="photo.jpg" alt="Test Photo" class="clipped" />
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.container{
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img.clipped {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

[image]

I would expect to see the center of the image in a 75 x 75 pixel container like below, i.e. vertically centered.

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images starts resizing from the top-left corner of the box, so only its bottom part is cut out.

You can achieve that result moving the image to the background:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/AGCW6/) - **Warning**: won't work on IE8

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    background:url(photo.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    background-size:75px auto; /* or background-size:100% auto; */
}​
```

---

To apply this method to multiple containers, you can split it in two classes:

```
.container {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}​

.myPic {
    background:url(photo.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    background-size:75px auto; /* or background-size:100% auto; */
}
```

Then you can have:

```
<div class="container myPic"></div>​
<div class="container2 myPic"></div>​
<div class="container myPic2"></div>​
<div class="container2 myPic2"></div>​
```

...and so on.

OR you can set the background-image with an inline style:

```
.container {
    /* same stuff */
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:75px auto; /* or background-size:100% auto; */
}
```

And

```
<div class="container" style="background-image:url(photo.jpg);">
<div class="container" style="background-image:url(photo2.jpg);">
```

Comment: How would I apply this class to multiple images? I won't be specifying the image as a background URL?

Comment: +1 The new solution (following edit) is indeed interesting if OP may change his HTML.

Comment: Let me try some of these.  Thanks for the great examples!

Comment: @Paul do you need a fallback for IE8?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a pure css solution, and I'm not sure there would be one reasonably simple for your HTML whatever the dimensions, but using javascript you might do this (adapt to [vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com/) if you don't use jQuery) :

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    $(this).scrollTop(($img.height()-$(this).height())/2);
    $(this).scrollLeft(($img.width()-$(this).width())/2);
});​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vgkGD/)

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve so maybe I need to do this like you mentioned during page load with jQuery if it's not possible with CSS

Comment: Using jQuery for this is overkill. You can achieve the same thing through pure CSS; see @GionaF's solution (I was about to post the exact same thing myself).

Comment: @daGUY My solution doesn't involve html change, even for numerous images, and is compatible with IE8. But it's true that the new solution given by GionaF is interesting (I upvoted it).

Answer (score 1):

One way for modern browsers that support translateY.

```
.clipped {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/5qts9jt5/130/

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  line-height: 73px;
}
.container img.clipped {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```